# Recommendations for small hosting solution with lots of support

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, vpn

I maintain a personal website though have never put much effort in building up the front-end.  I really just use it as a testbed for various projects I'm working on or tinkering with.  For a few years I've maintained an account with Hostgator but they've gotten to the point where I'm rather fed up.

Anyone have recommendations on best alternative?  I don't need a ton of space, or bandwidth, but I do need full ssh access, ftp access, php, perl, mysql, etc.. the basics.., and the ability to modify or change the php installation and install various packages (ruby, php, python is an extra plus) and I don't want to pay an arm and a leg.

Doesn't exist.. yeah, I know.

Comment: At the moment I'm leaning towards Linode https://www.linode.com/

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that full SSH access, I believe it is not possible in shared environment. You get jailed shell access for it.

Your other requirements are mostly fulfilled by every hosting provider.